# Outputting value to another function whilst continuing loop

Tags: python, loops

G'afternoon. I currently have a loop using Python v2.x that continually detects information through the wireless card. What I am looking to implement is, if the loop for example detects a known packet (identified through a comparison equation within the loop), the value of the known packet will be passed to another function for further processing (email to sysadmin for example) whilst the original loop continues to run simultaneously whilst the email is being created.

Would this need threading or given I'm using a loop, would this continue automatically? I am assuming that once an identified value is passed to another function, the loop would stop but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need either multi-thread or multi-processing.

```
for pkt in pkts:
    if pkt=="known packet":
        spawnNewThreadOrProcess(pkt)
        doOtherStuff()
```

If you don't spawn a new thread or process the statements will be executed in sequence and not simultaneously.

I want to add that if you are handing off the known packet to a function that underneath spawns a new process of thread anyway then obviously you don't need to worry about it. But the point is that the loop will execute statements in sequence unless a new thread of execution or a process is spawned.

Answer (score 0):

(As you might expect) it depends on what you mean by *simultaneously*. If you have a loop

```
while 1:
    info = get_sensor_info()
    if is_important(info):
        email(info)
```

then the loop will not stop just because you have called another function! Of course, `email`, being part of the loop, will be executed in sequence.

That is, the sequence of events will look like:

- Get sensor info. **Then**:
- If the info is important, email it. **Then**:
- Get sensor info again. **Then**:
- If the info is important, email it. **Then**:
- ...

It sounds like this should be fine for your purposes. On the other hand, maybe the email takes a while, and you don't want to stop reading from the sensor while it's being composed/sent. Then you would need to fire off a separate thread/process to do the actual sending.